# RethinkDB - Filter using Match() by value in same dataset and table

Tags: go, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, nosql

So, since I'm too dumb obviously to figure this out myself, I'll ask you better folks here on SO instead.

Basically i have a datastructure that looks like the following:

```
....,
{
 "id": 12345

 ....

 "policy_subjects": [
   {
     "compiled":  "^(user|max|anonymous)$",
     "template":  "<user|max|anonymous>"
   },
   {
     "compiled":  "^max$",
     "template":  "max"
   }
 ]
....
}
```

**compiled** is a "compiled" regex

**template** is the same regex without regex-modifiers

---

What I want is to do a simple query in RethinkDB using the "compiled" value and matching that against a string, say "max".

```
Basically 

r.table("regex_policies").filter(function(policy_row) {
  return "max".match("(?i)"+policy_row("policy_subjects")("compiled"))
}

Is what i want to do (+case-insensitive search)
```

There are of course lots of policy_subjects in the database so in this example the result should be the whole dataset (1 result) that matches "max". Since "max" exists twice in this case and it matches both regexes (once would have been enough).

"foobar" would likewise in this example yield 0 results, since any of the compiled regexes does not match "foobar".

Does anyone know how to do this relatively simple query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to use `r.expr` here and I got this example to work:

```
r.expr([{
 "id": 12345,
 "policy_subjects": [
   {
     compiled:  "^(user|max|anonymous)$",
     template:  "<user|max|anonymous>"
   },
   {
     compiled:  "^max$",
     template:  "max"
   }
 ]
}]).merge(function(policy_row) {  
  return {
    "policy_subjects": policy_row("policy_subjects").filter(function(item){
            return r.expr("max").match(r.expr("(?i)").add(item("compiled"))).ne(null);
        })
  }
})
```

Changing `max` to something else that does not match, returns the document with no elements inside `policy_subjects`.

For example, changing `max` => to `wat` (my favorite test string of all time) looks like this:

```
.merge(function(policy_row) {  
  return {
    "policy_subjects": policy_row("policy_subjects").filter(function(item){
            return r.expr("wat").match(r.expr("(?i)").add(item("compiled"))).ne(null);
        })
  }
})
```

And results in this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 12345 ,
    "policy_subjects": [ ]
  }
]
```

I think your logic for reducing to the one `policy_subject` document you want might be a little subjective to your use case so I'm not sure what the right answer is but you can use `.reduce(...)` to just return the right-most value.

Comment: Thank you dalanmiller! The merge part did the trick and i can now fully fetch the data :)